# AngularJS 1 approach for "new foobar" UI overlay

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I'm using AngularJS 1 with angular-material and ui-router.

Does anyone know what the best practice is for providing a UI for some "new foobar" type thing? In other words, let’s say I have a ui.route putting me at `/app/#/foobars/` which shows a list of all the foobars. At the bottom right is a FAB with a big plus sign, which will bring up a new UI something to allow the user to specify how they want their foobar. What is the best practices for this "UI something" that comes up, using Angular?

- Should I use an angular-material dialog? (That’s my first inclination, but it seems old-fashioned.)
- Do I create a route to `/app/#/new-foobar/` and just bring up another UI? (This seems heavy-handed; I don’t want to change the URI, plus I probably want to get back to where I came from after creating the foobar.)
- I think that ui-router allows nested states; is this something I would use? But I don't want the new view/component to be embedded in the current view --- I would expect a card or something to somehow "overlay" whatever view is showing.

Comment: Use $stateProvider in ui-router. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use nested states for this, as they are intended for things such a master/detail navigation.
The answer to your question is "it depends", as many situations in programming there're always some tradeoffs you must consider. Depending if you're targeting a desktop or a mobile app you'll have more or less space to put these options on the screen. If there're a lot of configuration options you should define a completly different state on wich you layout them and apply this configuration when you come back to the list. If there are not too much of them or you want to keep them visible at the same time as the list, you can go with a SideNav panel that can be locked open depending on the resolution. An alternative I've used sometimes is using a subheader to show some controls, as you can make it "stick" below the header or let it go if you scroll the list. As I told you before is a matter of choices and tradeoffs, and some sense of usability and simplicity towards the final user. There's no silver bullet nor best practice, just follow your intuition. Good luck!

Comment: The Sidenav sounds very interesting. But how do I make it work? Where do I put the HTML for the Sidenav and load it all in, connect the controller, etc. whenever the FAB is pressed? I certainly don't want to hard-code the HTML in the main page, and I probably want to reuse the panel. I don't know the mechanism for dynamically loading this if I'm not using nested states.

Comment: Even worse, the sidenav isn't responsive. It's stuck at a certain pixel width, and I would have to muck with the styling just to get it looking half-way correct. It doesn't seem to have been made for this.

Comment: If you want to reuse the panel then you should put it's contents into a component or a directive. Furthermore, the responsiveness of the SideNav resides on it's hability to stay open in larger resolutions and be hidden and triggered by a button on smaller screens.